# URL blocking in OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt

I have Asus RT-N16 router. Stock latest firmware has DualWAN settings, but it works definitely bad - some days (when ISP1 is not stable and dualwan operating?) when I open websites router frequently redirects me to 192.168.1.1. I checked 2 devices, both works same way.
One day I decided to change firmware, I read that OpenWRT is powerful, stable, etc. 
So I installed new firmware, latest Chaos Calmer 15.05. Then installed mwan3 package for multiwan features. Works stable, ok. 
But I did not found a simplest feature, that even stock firmware have, in admin panel - URL website filter. After googling I found some posts with crazy solutions, like manually (console) setting ip routes/hosts for every url or installing cache servers.
Is there a simple solution/package for URL/keyword domain blocking (parental control) for OpenWRT or do I need to search another firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do changes in firewall file, if u don't have memory to install additional packages. You just find the IP of website and add it to the firewall file with input, output and forward as reject. I have done this, and its works for me.

```
uci set firewall.block=rule
uci set firewall.block.name=anything
uci set firewall.block.src=lan
uci set firewall.block.dest=wan
uci set firewall.block.dest_ip=ipaddr
uci set firewall.block.target=reject
```

and if u want to block sites from wan then just:

```
uci set firewall.block.src=wan
uci set firewall.block.dest=lan
```

Answer (score 0):

Good to know that you are using OpenWRT.
So there are plenty of packages available in OpenWRT this is feature you requested is also available check this package called [tiny proxy](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.tinyproxy)
I used it it works like a Charm.

Comment: Ok, luci app installed, but where can I find guide to configure it? I think popular app must have many guides, but there is no one at all.

Comment: try this [blog](http://jakehe.blogspot.in/2014/10/openwrt-site-filtering-with-tinyproxy.html) or this [wiki](jakehe.blogspot.in/2014/10/openwrt-site-filtering-with-tinyproxy.html) I know this is related to slackware but this can help you understand config cause packege is same just platform is differant